# Spell checking package for Texlive

Tags: spelling

Is there any package for texlive to check spelling and replace the right spelling in an  interactive way? I can use command line 'aspell' or 'ispell' checker but these do not modify the .tex file only correct for the instant compilation.

Comment: Yo can use the open/libre office dictionaries in TeXmaker/TeXstudio also. But I'm not sure if this satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the terminal, you can use `aspell` as an independent program to spell-check TeX files, outside of any editor. The `-t` option tells the program to ignore the TeX commands.

```
 aspell -t check file.tex
```

Comment: I know that. As I mentioned for a long technical document  writing this is not great as I have to do this after each editing of the tex file. I need something that will check and correct or replace permanently in the texfile.

Comment: Aspell, when used as a separate program in the terminal, does change the .tex file. This is unrelated to the text editor you use. You would have to save the file in your text editor and then run this command separately. When you reopen the file, the misspelled words will be corrected as you directed `aspell` to do.

Comment: Oh may be I did not close it in the tex editor that's why the replacement had not taken place!! Thank you !!